# Cocoa - How to get Mouse Down Events when mouse isn't Dragging?

Tags: cocoa, event-handling, mouse

Cocoa, Mac OS X 10.6.

My app (a game) needs to determine if the mouse is down within a view, repeatedly, even if the mouse position doesn't change.

The problem:

- `mouseDown` will only be called the first time the mouse is pressed and held down. If the mouse is *not* moved at this point, `mouseDragged` is not called, and no more `mouseDown` events are generated.

Question: how do I determine that the mouse is still down after that initial (and only) `mouseDown` event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something periodically while the mouse is down, have `mouseDown:` create a repeating [timer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/), and have `mouseUp:` tear it down.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It seems a bit unwieldy -- would have preferred a system level approach -- but will try this.  It seems a curious omission on the Cocoa team's part to me, since it sorta pushes people to a polling approach which is not great. Cheers.

Comment: SirRatty: Timers are not polling.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether the mouse is down or not, set a `BOOL` variable in `mouseDown:` and `mouseUp:`.

If you want to keep doing something while the mouse is down, you can enter a mouse tracking loop as explained here: [The Mouse-Tracking Loop Approach](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW4) Basically you loop until you find the mouse up event, and you can do whatever you want in the loop. You will have to use `nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:` instead of `nextEventMatchingMask:` and set the `untilDate` to something short.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  Since it's a game, I need to interpret these games asynchronously.  That is, over time, so I need to get the event then pass them off to the game logic. (Thus I can't stay in a tight loop.)

Answer (score 0):

CGEventSourceButtonState(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState, kCGMouseButtonLeft));

is what you are after on 64 bit. (ok 4 years late).

// mozzilla...

```
     1.30  #ifdef XP_MACOSX
     1.31 -  // hacky OS call to ensure that we don't show a context menu when the user
     1.32 -  // let go of the mouse already, after a long, cpu-hogging operation prevented
     1.33 +  // Hack to ensure that we don't show a context menu when the user
     1.34 +  // let go of the mouse after a long cpu-hogging operation prevented
     1.35    // us from handling any OS events. See bug 117589.
     1.36 -  if (!::StillDown())
     1.37 +  if (!CGEventSourceButtonState(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState, kCGMouseButtonLeft))
    1.38      return;
    1.39  #endif
```